# CURL multiple times

Tags: php, curl, cron

```
$hotel_query = "select hotel_id,hotel_name,trip_url,automatic_status from hotels where automatic_status='0'";
$hotel_result = mysql_query($hotel_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($hotel_row = mysql_fetch_object($hotel_result))
{
     $url=$hotel_row->trip_url;
     $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

The above code is running via cron job in php.There are 5 trip_url in hotels `table`. It means curl should execute 5 times and return result from server 5 times but 
but when I run this only one result is printed and stop executing.

Comment: try using this: mysql_fetch_array($hotel_result))

Comment: Are you sure that the query is working... try putting print_r($hotel_row); inside the while loop so that it echos each time round. If that gives you 5 results then we can move on from there

Comment: yes it is giving 5 results.@chris

Comment: Then I think maybe your Curl code is flawed, have a go with the code I posted below - see what happens

Comment: `curl_error($ch);` is after `curl_close($ch);`. At that point `$ch` is not a curl resource anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php

function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }    
    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();    
    // Now set some options (most are optional)    
    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);    
    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");    
    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");    
    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    
    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);    
    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);    
    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $output;
}

$loop_counter = 1;
$hotel_query = "select hotel_id,hotel_name,trip_url,automatic_status from hotels where automatic_status='0'";
$hotel_result = mysql_query($hotel_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($hotel_row = mysql_fetch_object($hotel_result)){
     $url=$hotel_row->trip_url;
    echo "Loop no.".$loop_counter."<br />";
    echo curl_download($url);
    $loop_counter++;
}



?>
```

The CURL code is from [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)

Comment: Have you tried manually opening the links to make sure the pages exist?

Comment: Ok - so is it giving the same 1 result five times, or does it only output once and die? - Try the new updated code above